# React - populating data for a table with row header and column header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, html-table

I have to build and populate a table that has a row header and a column header.
Something like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th scope="col">January</th>
    <th scope="col">February</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>$90</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The data I get from the API is in the format:

```
{
    item: '1',
    month: 'January',
    res:0,
    savings: 100
  },
  {
    item: '1',
    month: 'February',
    res: 0,
    savings: 80,
  },
  {
    item: '2',
    month: 'January',
    savings: 90,
  },
  {
    item: '2',
    month: 'February',
    res: 0
    savings: 80
  },
```

Here's what I tried:

```
render() {
const contents = data[0].groupDetail.values.map(testData => {
      return <tr>
        <td>{testData.item}</td>
        <td>{testData.month}</td>
        <td>{testData.savings}</td>
      </tr>
    })
return(
<table>
              <tr>
                 <th></th>
        <th scope="col">January</th>
        <th scope="col">February</th>
              </tr>

                {contents}
</table>
)}
```

I am unsure how to convert this data to populate the table. I tried .map and each item appeared twice. Can some one please help with the approach here? Thanks!!

> UPDATE: Here's what I have now:

```
const grouped = _.groupBy(data[0].groupDetail.values, data => data.item);

let result = Object.keys(grouped).map(key => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>
            {key}
          </td>
          {Object.keys(grouped[key]).map(itemText => {
            return (
              <td>
                {grouped[key][itemText]['fieldName']}
              </td>
            )
          })}
        </tr>
      );
    });
```

Comment: Please show what you tried. The objective here is to help you fix your code not to be a free code writing service

Comment: @charlietfl I've updated to show you what was tried. The html is similar to what I mentioned in the question originally, I've added the .map I tried. Appreciate the help you provide!

Comment: you can't do this with a single map(). You need to first reduce the data into columns using a `groupBy` approach then iterate all the groups to create properly ordered row data in a 2d array.

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl for pointing me in the right direction. So this is what I have now - but there's still a problem. Some fields may be missing in the data I receive, and I dont know how to fill them as null so the table wont be populated there. Question updated with the groupBy code. This fills in the first columns, then leaves the remaining empty. But the data could have been just for the last column.

Comment: So will the headings always be fixed regardless of data? If so can use those to create the initial grouping object. Something like this is probably easiest to work on without doing it in JSX first and just do it with data in a sandbox and logging to console until you get structure that can be plugged into JSX rendering

Answer (score 0):

This should work =)

```
const items = [{
    item: '1',
    month: 'January',
    savings: 100,
  },
  {
    item: '1',
    month: 'February',
    savings: 80,
  },
  {
    item: '2',
    month: 'January',
    savings: 90,
  },
  {
    item: '2',
    month: 'February',
    savings: 80,
  }
];

const groupBy = (objectArray, property) => {
  return objectArray.reduce(function(acc, obj) {
    const key = obj[property];
    if (!acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = [];
    }
    acc[key].push(obj);
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

const groupedItems = groupBy(items, 'item');

  return (
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th scope="col">January</th>
        <th scope="col">February</th>
      </tr>
      {Object.keys(groupedItems).map(item => (
          <tr>
            <td>{item}</td>
              {groupedItems[item].map(item => (
                <td>{item.savings}</td>
              ))}
          </tr>
      ))}
    </table>
  )
```

Comment: Thanks @weibenfalk! That's lean! And this still results in the same problem - If there is a missing field in the dataset, it gets populated under the incorrect header. I've updated the dataset in the question to give you an example of what kind of missing data I'm referring to. I've added a `res: 0` in some of the rows.

Comment: That's strange. It's working here when I test in a sandbox. It shouldn't matter how many properties you have in your data object. We're not using the res value at all. Just grabbing the item.saving value. I just tested it with your new values in the data array. It works =) You have a type error in your last data object though.. should be a "," after the last res: 0

Off course .. if you're using the res value somehow I can't see it here. But I guess you won't use it?

Comment: Do you mind sharing a jsfiddle link? If a value is missing, that particulare cell in the table should be empty. But unfortunately for this row: `{
    item: '2',
    month: 'January',
    savings: 90,
  },` the value 90 renders under the 'res' header.

Comment: Ok .. didn't thought that you were going to use the res as you didn't mention it in your original code and question =) You have to modify the function then to take that into account also.